# Apache Test failing

Tags: apache2

please assist my apache2 test is failing below is the error that i get

```
Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: 
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1: <Virtual> was not closed.
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's your issue:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1: <Virtual> was not closed.
```

edit your 000-default.conf file to correct the virtual host block, close it properly.

Comment: If you're unsure what to do exactly - it may also help if you copy your config here, so someone can get it corrected properly for you. But that shouldn't be really a difficult fix for you anyway.

Comment: Hi, the file is empty

Comment: That's a bit bizarre, I'd say. You can disable this config if you don't use it (a2dissite 000-default). But all the rest depends actually on what exactly you're after with your apache installation - it may be worth to have a quick reading on VirtualHost configuration in apache.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName rt:80
redirect /https://rt.localhost

#ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
#DocumentRoot /var/www
do find the code

Comment: I see - you have to close the section with </VirtualHost>, as far as I see.

Comment: Have a look at this document: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: I have managed to solve that now have challenges with the below,,
Set( $rt, 'example.com');
Set( $ictdynamix.co.bw, 'corp.example.com')
Set( $rt.ictdynamix.co.bw, 'rt.corp.example.com');
Set( $80, 443);
 i managed to get to licensing part put it returns nothin

Comment: These are Request Tracker settings as far as I see - for that I'd recommend BestPractical's manual on RT installation (yes, it may be sometimes a bit tricky at the beggining). If you get to your proper virtual host address, but get empty page or so - I'd recommend to start with logs to see what happens there.